# Can a params array be a holding type for a list in C#?

Tags: c#

Can a params[] variable hold a list, that has been passed as a parameter through a method in C#?

Wrote a method(AddIntegers) which requires multiple values to be taken as parameters. On the parameter list of a method, there is a params[] variable that is receiving the values thrown, when the method call is made in the Main method. But there is an exception that says "Cannot convert from system.collections.generic.List<> to an integer. Anyone knows why does that happen?

```
       **** this is within the Main Method**** 
        string Demostring = Console.ReadLine();
        string[] tokens = Demostring.Split(',');
        List<int> nums = new List<int>();
        int oneNum;
        foreach(string s in tokens)
        {
            if (Int32.TryParse(s, out oneNum))
                nums.Add(oneNum);
        }

        int result1 = AddIntegers(nums);

        **** this is the method to be called****
        public static int AddIntegers(params int[] Restnum)
        {
            int result = 0;

            foreach(int temp in Restnum)
            {
                result += temp;
            }

             return result;
         }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, a `List<int>` isn't an `int[]`, so you can't use it as an argument for an `int[]` parameter. (The fact that it's a parameter array doesn't change that.)

Typically the solution to this is to have two overloads - one accepting a parameter array and one accepting an `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
public static int AddIntegers(params int[] numbers) =>
    AddIntegers((IEnumerable<int>) numbers);

public static int AddIntegers(IEnumerable<int> numbers)
{
    ...
}
```

Note that for this specific example, you can just call the `Sum` extension method from LINQ to Objects, of course.

There are proposals for parameter arrays to be able to accept `IReadOnlyList<T>` rather than just `T[]`, but that isn't in C# yet. (I'd love it, personally...)

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are trying to insert a List inside an array parameter.

Instead of this:

`int result1 = AddIntegers(nums);`

You could do this:

`int result1 = AddIntegers(nums.ToArray());`

Or alternatively:

```
public static int AddIntegers(List<int> numbers)
{
     return AddIntegers(numbers.ToArray());
}

public static int AddIntegers(params int[] Restnum)
{
    int result = 0;

    foreach(int temp in Restnum)
    {
        result += temp;
    }

    return result;
}
```

And then call it like you normally would.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            const string demostring = "1,2,3,4,5,6";
            var tokens = demostring.Split(',');
            var nums = new List<int>();
            foreach (var s in tokens)
                if (int.TryParse(s, out var oneNum))
                    nums.Add(oneNum);

            var result1 = AddIntegers(nums);
        }
        public static int AddIntegers(List<int> restnum)
        {
            var result = 0;

            foreach (var temp in restnum)
                result += temp;

            return result;
        }
```